# AngularJS Modal keeps values even when the scope is reset

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using the `Materialize` modal, and I have:

```
$scope.initUpsertModal = function(userId) {
  var userPromise;
  if (userId) {
    userPromise = $http.get("/api/users/" + userId);
  } else {
    userPromise = Promise.resolve({
      data: {
        status: 'active',
        type: 'mentor'
      }
    });
  }
  return userPromise.then(function(response) {
    $scope.currentUser = response.data;
    return $('#userModal').openModal();
  });
};
```

When I open the modal with a `userId`, all is well. Then I close the modal and move on with my life. I then open the modal with no `userId` and somehow the modal has the data from the previous time it was opened.

In my view, I have
`<ng-include src="'/views/modals/userUpsert.html'"></ng-include>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing is destroying the scope of the modal.  You're simply hiding it.

You should hook into the `complete` callback that gets called on modalClose

```
$('.modal-trigger').leanModal({
      complete: function() { // destroy scope } 
    }
  );
```